# Help identifying houseplant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I got this houseplant from a grocery store, and there was no card or anything identifying the type of plant. It’s looking a little droopy, so I wanted to try and figure out what kind of plant it was to better care for it. The leaves are a bit waxy but only slightly, and it doesn’t flower. I’ll attach a few photos, any help is appreciated[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there anything printed on the plastic pot?

Comment: no, just a barcode and a price

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me somewhat like a Crape-Jasmine plant.
Here is a picture of what one looks like (It looks quite similar):
[image: crape jasmine plant]